# USB connection not working VUSB

Tags: avr, usb

```
ar 29 22:12:14 stevendesktop kernel: [ 4265.290019] usb 5-1: device descriptor read/64, error -62
Mar 29 22:12:15 stevendesktop kernel: [ 4265.572782] usb 5-1: new low speed USB device using ohci_hcd and address 52
Mar 29 22:12:15 stevendesktop kernel: [ 4265.990018] usb 5-1: device not accepting address 52, error -62
Mar 29 22:12:15 stevendesktop kernel: [ 4266.160020] usb 5-1: new low speed USB device using ohci_hcd and address 53
Mar 29 22:12:16 stevendesktop kernel: [ 4266.580018] usb 5-1: device not accepting address 53, error -62
Mar 29 22:12:16 stevendesktop kernel: [ 4266.580032] hub 5-0:1.0: unable to enumerate USB device on port 1
```

These are the messages that appear in the logs when I connect my avr. What could of caused these errors.

pin D-
I  have D- connected to a 68R resistor in series. The other end goes to my avr. I wired a 1.5K pull in parallel to the 68ohm resistor. A zener 0.5w 3.6v parallel to pin 2 of the type A socket.

pin D+
Wires in series to a 68ohm resistor. The other end to avr. A zener in parallel to the D+ pin. Also wired to int0 pin.

It's self powered at the moment so therefore I don't need to connect the 5v and gnd pins right?

When I connected the D+ pin to my scope I could see a square wave being generated. I tested the frequency it's bang on 16MHZ. Though I did notice occasionally it went down to 15.98.

So what could be wrong?

Comment: Both zener diodes should be on the USB connector side of the 68$\Omega$ resistors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> pin D- I have D- connected to a 68R
>   resistor in series. The other end goes
>   to my avr. I wired a 1.5K pull in
>   parallel to the 68ohm resistor. A
>   zener 0.5w 3.6v parallel to pin 2 of
>   the type A socket.

sounds like your pulling D- up to your board's supply (it should be pulled up to 3.3V), at least i think thats what your trying to say.  If the 1.5k is actually in parallel with the 68 ohm resistor, that is a problem.

As you haven't connected the ground from the USB link, the other end has no reference at all for what you've pulled that pin up to.  Nor is your controller seeing the pull downs on the host side of the link.

Connect the ground from the USB link to your board ground.

Answer (score 0):

Do you use a 16MHz quartz crystal or a ceramic oscillator? The accuracy required by the USB standard is far higher then what your scope (or most simple frequency counters) could measure.

Comment: That's not necessarily true. Low speed USB mode (which the poster is using judging from his pull-up placement on D-) is fairly lenient, and new versions of VUSB are designed to work with the interal oscillator of the AVR. See http://www.obdev.at/products/vusb/easylogger.html

Comment: "V-USB can currently handle clock rates of 12 MHz, 12.8 MHz, 15 MHz, 16 MHz, 16.5 MHz, 18 MHz and 20 MHz. These clock rates are precise! A crystal with 11.9 MHz won't work! Only the 16.5 MHz and 12.8 MHz variants allow a deviation of up to 1%. They are therefore suitable for RC oscillators. 16.5 MHz is suitable for devices which can derive a 16 MHz clock from an RC oscillator (e.g. ATTiny25/45/85 and ATTiny26), 12.8 MHz can usually be reached by calibrating the 8 MHz RC oscillator. Calibration of the RC oscilator is described at examples."

Comment: Solved I just needed to wire my circuit gnd to the gnd pin of my usb port

Answer (score 0):

If I were you I would study the reference project for using the internal clock with a 5v design carefully. It's the [EasyLogger](http://www.obdev.at/products/vusb/easylogger.html).
You can download the schematic from the archives at the bottom.

Comment: Strange issue. My circuit does work but only is it's grounded using the ground clip on my scope. why?

Comment: Sheer Luck? In general while the computer (== USB host) ground and the scope ground could be the same, you have no guarantee that they are.